# recognized command (autofile) does not work when I create a file

Tags: html, django, file, visual-studio-code

Hello friends I work through the VScode platform
And also works with django,
And I have a problem when I create a templates folder and within it I want to create an HTML file
And when I type the html command it does not complete it for me automatically as if it does not recognize the file.
But if I create a file in another folder in the project he recognizes it very nicely.
Here are some pictures to illustrate.

[Here you can see the path when I create an html file I have the autocomplete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLFAk.png)

[And here when I create a file inside a template folder it does not know to recognize.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRfz5.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce, what is the languageID of the file, bottom right status bar

Comment: i find the solution